# Node.js or Express.js REST API document generator

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a restAPI using Express.js and I'm wondering if there is a way for me to generate API documents that allow a user to view API definitions or possibly even try out the API call?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Swagger is an amazing project for auto generating API documentation. It includes an Express module.

http://swagger.io/

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-node-express

Comment: Thanks @dankohn. I'm checking it out.

Comment: Do these auto generate based on routes configured in express?

Comment: @lostintranslation AFAIK they don't. Swagger documentation is saved in yml files.

Comment: @UbaidAzad I updated the link to http://swagger.io/, it should be visible on the answer once the edit is peer reviewed.

Comment: Most of these tools require generating a new project and or completely scaffolding, very useful for the beginning of a project, their generation seems useless for a project that already exists.

Comment: I tried to implement the Swagger, which was painful especially with TS. Surprised there isn't something that does this automatically.

Answer (score 109):

What you are looking for is a good JavaScript documentation generator.  I found a decent one here http://apidocjs.com/example/.
This will allow you to use just Express as OP asked.

Swagger isn't for *generating* docs, it's for *making* APIs.  So you are going to need to learn a full system to get that feature.

I found a couple more here that I haven't fully looked into yet which seem promising:
Docco [here](http://jashkenas.github.io/docco/) JSDoc [here](http://usejsdoc.org/) and [an  article on Documentor for Node](http://samwize.com/2014/01/31/the-best-documentation-generator-for-node/)

Answer (score 3):

I found this library to be very useful when it comes to keeping your documentation and route declaration logic close together:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc

Comment: Looks great, did you ever run into any issues while using this?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Postman while developing you might already have a Postman collection containing the most relevant calls.
If that is the case Postman has a docs feature https://learning.postman.com/docs/publishing-your-api/documenting-your-api/